# Can't add line break while storing string to a txt file in PHP

Tags: php, echo, line-breaks, fwrite

Simple code to learn how to open, write to a txt file and read it. I am having two issues.

1. I can't seem to add an actual line break while storing string in .txt file.
2. Echo is NOT printing the text in the browser

**Code**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$myfile=fopen("testfile.txt", "a") or die("unable to open file");
$txt=("john doe<br>");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt=("jane doe<br>");
fwrite($myfile,$txt);
echo fread($myfile, filesize("testfile.txt"));

?>
</body>
</html>
```

*contents of .txt file* ( as you can see it is literally adding line break tag in the txt file instead of adding a break)

```
john doe<br>jane doe<br>
```

Also please suggest why the echo is not printing when I run the PHP file in Chrome.

Comment: you might want to clarify about the echoing, at the top you said the second problem is that it is echoing while then later you say *"why the echo is not printing"*

Comment: in regards to the line break in your file. `<br>` is not a line break. it's a html tag to create a new line in a browser. if you want to linebreak in a file generally you need in the string `\r\n`, or append the string with the `PHP_EOL` constant to add in the end of line characters's that are configured for your php installation (mine is `\r\n`)

Comment: 'a' opens the file for writing only, that's why you cant read from it

Comment: Please [read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about urgent begging, and be informed that this is not an appropriate way to address volunteers. Thanks!

Comment: `PHP_EOL` - The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: Thanks I have fixed the first problem with using the PHP_EOL constant. I have WAMP installed on my windows machine and I am trying to run the php file in a browser. Local host server is in the path for the browser. As per the code, it should echo the contents of the .txt file on the browser but it is not. Any thoughts???

Also I have made a note about not saying "Urgent" :-) Thanks for educating! Help is appreciated.

Comment: changed the open variable from a to a+ so that I can read also but it doesn't help. I need someone to help me with reading part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part
The proper code would be

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$myfile=fopen("testfile.txt", "a") or die("unable to open file");
$txt=("john doe\n");
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt=("jane doe\n");
fwrite($myfile,$txt);
echo fread($myfile, filesize("testfile.txt"));
?>
</body>
</html>
```

`<br>` is a html tag and is rendered only in browser, for files you should use carriage return which is `\n`

As far as second question goes, i think that you are trying to open the .php file directly in browser, That is not the proper way to do that. Browser can only run js files. The php files run on your server, (usually apache/nginx). You can find a lot of manuals on how to configure them with php and the view the rendered output in browser.

Comment: Yes I am trying to open the file in a browser. But I have WAMP installed and I am opening with the full address accessing the server(local host) and so it should work. The first problem is now resolved but it still doesn't echo???

http://localhost/first/file.php

Comment: @user3529770 in the source code of browser are you looking at php code or compiled output from php ?

Comment: Its weird when I click view source on the browser after running the php file. Its only showing me code for a blank page as opposed to the php code above. See below.


<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user3529770 you need to print out contents of file also.Rather than fread try `echo readfile($myfile)`

Comment: Thanks readfile worked but I am still unsure why would the combination of echo and fread not work because echo is supposed to print the contents, right??

Comment: @user3529770 i am not sure about the fread syntax, read docs maybe you implemented something wrong. I prefer to use readfile as it is hastle free. Also if this answer helped please accept it :)

Comment: Thanks this for very helpful! Not sure if you want me to click somewhere answer accepted, let me know! :-)

Comment: On left of answer there is a tick button under vote. You can click on that to accept answer. Not sure if you will be able to vote that requires more permission

Answer (score 0):

For line break you are using <br> tag, it's line break for HTML. To write new line in file you can use PHP_EOL. It's PHP constant that adds \n for UNIX alike system and \r\n for windows, resulting line break in the file.

```
// Concat new line to string
$txt = "john doe".PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);

// Concat new line to string
$txt = "jane doe".PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
```